# Prestashop REST API returning bad HTTP response with PHP client

Tags: prestashop

This code:

```
try {
    // creating webservice access
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice('https://149.28.159.206/', '6DE5PU9M9SC7RZCRFF4VK3MFDVVTGRJT', false);

    // call to retrieve all customers
    $xml = $webService->get(['resource' => 'products']);
} catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
    // Shows a message related to the error
    echo 'Other error: <br />' . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Is returning the following error:

```
Other error: <br />Bad HTTP response
```

And I have activated the key with the appropriate permissions (please see attached screenshot). Yet, it's giving this error.

[image]

May I know why, and how I can solve this?

I am using Prestashop 1.7.6.5 on Ubuntu 18.04 x64, from a vultr.com cloud instance.

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop use Domain/api for webservics.

try "https://149.28.159.206/api/"

Comment: it keeps redirecting to index.php. why does this happen?

Comment: Maybe try this:
https://wordcodepress.com/prestashop-1-7-webservice-api-401-unauthorized/